# Azure - Windows VM not accessible

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I have a Windows VM in my Azure account. It was working fine until I changed its size to increase resources / disk size.  After the update VM stopped working. I am unable to access VM with RDP or FTP etc.

I have tried restarting VM but still same. Any clue how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several tried, I used ***Reset Remote Access*** option. This seems to have made the VM accessible again. But unfortunately it has changed VM Ip address too.